# Boot to... Nothing

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, xposed-framework

I was planning to install xposed to my samsung tab 2 (Running lollipop. Somehow.) So naturally, I flashed the zip I needed in twrp. I tried rebooting, and the boot animation loads, then the screen goes blank. I've tried:

- Factory resets
- Just deleting /data (basically a dirty factory reset)
- wiping the Primary and davlik cache.
- Disabling my SWAP (Long story)
- Updating the xposed mod installed.
- Reinstalling ROM (Works until I turn it off, and then the nothingness happens again.)

**Anybody know how I can fix this?**

*Keep in mind that my tablet is running both a custom kernel and custom ROM (It is meant to be 4.2.2 stock). I also doubt I need the special samsung version, since I can get other devices to run without it (even tough they should need it)*

Comment: Samsung phones require a custom xposed version: http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/unofficial-xposed-samsung-lollipop-t3180960. Also keep in mind that a factory reset will not fix issues with `/system` where xposed is located.

Comment: @GiantTree well, a coupla things. First of all, my tab 2 jas a custom kernel and custom rom (after all, its supposed to be on 4.2.2 stock) and secondly, I have ran multiple versions of xposed without a special samsung version. I also (rather stupidly) thought it was an app conflict.

Comment: You may want to add this information to the question, so others have all information necessary to give better answers.

Comment: @GiantTree Done! Also added a bit I forgot.

Comment: Have you tried flashing the xposed uninstaller? That's what one usually does in such a case. Though re-flashing the clean ROM should have taken care for that as a side-effect. With the second side-effect that you've probably removed the backup files Xposed created on install and the uninstaller needs to revert the changes …

Comment: @Izzy Let me guess: XDA? All right, I will try it. BRB.

Comment: @DanB Yupp. Right where you found the installer, there you also find the uninstaller. Though it's most likely too late for that – as you've already done a factory-reset *and* re-flashed the ROM. Still, cannot hurt :)

Comment: @Izzy Damn it! Didnt work :( I will try patching the ROM again. Quick q - any idea on what "result was [0.2000000]" means??

Comment: Didn't suspect it would, after what you've already done (see above). Btw: When re-flashing the ROM, did you wipe everything? Last resort I could think of is wiping cache, data, *and system* and then flash the ROM again. Usually, ROM-flashing should take care of wiping system – so I'm not sure if this helps. Again, worth a try at least. If that doesn't fix it, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @Izzy just wiped /system on the current attempt. Its trying to boot now. I have to grab another copy of gapps now lol. At least we have google.

Comment: Ahem... Not that I use GApps anymore (I don't, I use microG instead) – but AFAIK one should flash GApps immediately after flashing the ROM *and before booting again.* So if you see your GApps "unfortunately" crashing: Go to start, do not collect $200, but flash the ROM *and* GApps :)

Comment: @Izzy Ah, I'll live. The nano package seems to be flashable at any time with no real issues. I still have my get out of jail free card - a friend has a tab 2 with an identical setup. All else fails, I'll just clone their entire system. **In other news, my tablet boots now. Yay!**